# Linux bridge and vlan configuration with Qemu/Libvirt VM

Tags: networking, qemu, bridge, libvirt, vlan

I am trying to forward traffic from my Qemu VMs to my pfSense VM with the help of vlan tagging.

I know that libvirt has no direct support for vlan traffic in conjunction with Linux bridges which is why I am not touching the interfaces that Qemu/libvirt is setting up for me (vnetA, vnetC, ..., vnetI in the picture). These vnets are also automatically added to a premade linux bridge by Qemu/libvirt (brB, brD, ..., brJ in the picture).

[image: Topology]

I am now trying to create a vlan subinterface on, for example, brB which will be called vlanB (in the system it shows up as vlanB@brB). This vlan subinterface is being added to the virtual_lan bridge which in turn is connected to my pfSense VM which then (if you get lucky with the vlan tagging) should answer the DHCP request and give the Ubuntu VM in this case a valid IP address.

This is what I have typed in so far:

1. `ip link set dev brB type bridge vlan_filtering 1`
2. `ip link add link brB name vlanB type vlan id 10`
3. `ip link set vlanB master virtual_lan`
4. `ip link set dev virtual_lan type bridge vlan_filtering 1`
5. `bridge vlan add dev vlanB vid 10`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please don't open [duplicate questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/1131464/linux-bridge-and-vlan-configuration-with-qemu-libvirt-vm) on multiple sites.

Comment: @larsks Applause for noticing that but I guess it would be better "to make a preliminary decision" on which site the question makes more sense and put such a comment on the other site only, avoiding closing on both simultaneously.

Comment: The other site did not allow me to post with pictures and this one did, thereof the duplicate question. Chances of someone actually taking the time of opening the link and then comparing my explanation side by side with my text seemed quite slim.

Comment: If you add vlan interfaces linked to the bridge interfaces themselves, then they are linked to the part of the bridge participating in routing, not in bridging: you get a bridge with a single port (vnetA but not vlanB) where nothing gets bridged.